# Python Sharepoint library Office365-REST-Python-Client ERROR: 401: Unauthorized for url: https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/sample/_api/Web

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am trying to use the [App-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs) flow for Share point.

First, I have created a new app client-id and secret with this URL https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/sample/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx.

Then I went to the URL https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/sample/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx to give permissions to this app with the following xml.

`<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true"> <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl"/> <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl"/> </AppPermissionRequests>`

and clicked on trust it.

The code that I am using :

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

site_url = 'https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/sample/'
app_principal = {
  'client_id': '.....-..',
  'client_secret': '......=',
}

context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=site_url)
context_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=app_principal['client_id'], 
client_secret=app_principal['client_secret'])

ctx = ClientContext(site_url, context_auth)
web=ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
if len(result) > 0:
    print("Folder has been found: {0}".format(result[0].properties["Name"]))
```

But it throws the following error :
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "client.py", line 16, in <module> ctx.execute_query() File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_runtime_context.py", line 140, in execute_query self.pending_request().execute_query() File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py", line 79, in execute_query raise ClientRequestException(*e.args, response=e.response) office365.runtime.client_request_exception.ClientRequestException: (None, None, '401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/sample/_api/Web')`

Need help.

Comment: @Erfan I instead chose the other way of implementation which is, using certificates and it worked but it's a different approach altogether. Somehow client_id and secret was not working even after following the documented steps.

Answer (score 2):

I follow your steps,but I could not reproduce your issue.
[image]

If your office365 tenant is created recently,you could try to run below command.

```
Set-SPOTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false
```

Tip:You need to update the SharePoint Online managed shell to the latest version.

Updated:
[image]

Comment: Hi, I managed to get the authentication working by taking a new approach instead of the client credentials flow. There is a certificate flow and is also supported by the python lib. Was it maybe because I had sharepoint online instead of the on-premise setup.

Comment: Do you have an on-prem office 365 setup?

Comment: No,I do not have one.

Comment: I followed this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly

Comment: No clue why the SharePoint app-only principal did not work but I can confirm that the Azure AD app-only works fine with the lib's ClientContext.connect_with_certificate

Comment: Actually,you could find app registered in sharepoint in Azure AD admin center.

Comment: I had to create a separate app in the Azure portal as mentioned in the walkthrough. The one i created in sharepoint appregnew.aspx was nowhere to be seen in the azure portal.

Comment: Although I do have the certificate flow working, just want to know now what is it that I was missing while setting up from the sharepoint portal with appinv and appregnew

Comment: The testTwoScope application is the app registered in SharePoint. Follow the official tutorial, it should be no problem.

Comment: `Set-SPOTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false` fixed the issues for me. Just make sure to wait a bit after running this command via Sharepoint Online Management Shell before making the requests. Keep in mind that Sharepoint extension does not work in Powershell on Linux, so you basically need a Windows machine run change this setting.